# Gradle Project Sync Failed cause Firebase installation in Android Studio

Tags: android, firebase, gradle

I'm trying to resolve this problem looking for the similar question as mine in Stackoverflow, I have spend 6 hours and I am not able to solve it.
I've created a new project in AndroidStudio (version 3.2) and I've installed Firebase Google. One mistake appear in Gradle, I show with a image:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vgTNi.png)

The code of app gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.android.estermateossaldana.cadenadefavores"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.1:15.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.1:15.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:16.0.1:15.0.0'
}
```

The code of build gradle:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.0'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.1'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Trying to solve with the indications of you, the code is like:
Gradel Build code:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.0'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.1.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

And the Gradle App code now is:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.android.estermateossaldana.cadenadefavores"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-media-compat:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.1:15.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.3:15.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:16.0.1:15.0.0'
}
```

I show you the error in the image:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zNDVz.png)

Version of Android Studio and Gradle: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PiEUW.png)
The option of Use default gradle wrapper is checked.

-------> New screenshot: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OifD8.png)

Comment: Welcome to SO. There is no `28.0.1` dependency of the `AppCompat`. Use `28.0.0`, then update your google services to: `com.google.gms:google-services:4.1.0'` and after, update all of your [firebase dependencies](https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup#available_libraries) and it will work fine after that. However, use **English** for this website. Remove the extra versions too: `16.0.1:15.0.0` -> `'16.0.1'` & the rest..

Comment: Thank u, sorry for the english. It was my first ask. I did all you said me and the problem persists

Comment: Can I see the output after rebuilding your project? Any screenshot or the codes you have tried? Please consider using English in your question, otherwise, this will be an off-topic question and it will be closed soon.

Comment: I posted another ask to can post a pic

Comment: Ok I just saw it. Add: `implementation 'com.android.support:support-media-compat:28.0.0'` to your dependencies in `build.gradle` to avoid-fix that issue. However, check what is the problem with the firebase dependencies. They don't have the latest version BTW. You should be using gradle v 3.2.0: `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.0'` replace this to your another build.gradle with the old version (if you have) and it will be solved I hope.

Comment: I've put the implementation line and it doesn't work. I've already put the classpath with gradle v 3.2.0..

Comment: Still the same error or a new one? Can I see a screenshot after you changes? Please add it in your question and don't send it as an answer :)

Comment: Thank you for still answering, I've just put the new code and new mistake dialog in the question window. I am desperate :(

Comment: Oh don't be. I've just sent an answer. Please check and try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add this to your `build.gradle` dependency too:

```
implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'
```

So the dependencies in `app/build.gradle` should be:

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-media-compat:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0' // added this
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.4' 
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.4'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.3'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:16.0.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}
```

Remember to check the [samples](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android) and the [libraries section](https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup#available_libraries).

Comment: After do that, the error appear in de Event Log Window with the message: "Gradle sync failed ". I gonna check the samples...

Comment: Yes. Of course. What version of Android Studio you are using? Updating Android studio will help. Or, check the link I've provided in the answer. It seems like there is a problem with the gradle which I need to see what causes that issue. Now, your build.gradle seems working.

Comment: I am using 3.2.0 version of Android Studio, and 4.6 version of Gradle: I've posted the pic to you can check it

Comment: If the errors from `build.gradle` and the dependencies disappeared, there must be another issues with the project.  Could you please check to see if there is any other errors which you might see? In the build section or anywhere? You can however try to rebuild project from `build -> rebuild project`. Can't help you without checking any helpful errors-logs.

Comment: I'm thinking about maybe it is a problem when I create the database in Firedata? I am not sure.. One of the mistake we can see on the path, I'm posting the screenshot on the down of my question

Comment: You're **still retrieving the same error** as before. Please just **copy-paste my pasted codes** inside your `app/build.gradle` (inside dependency) and then it will work fine. Updated my answer, please take a look again.

Comment: Thank u, with your code the error has disappear, although now my app is not connect to firebase... I'll continue testing... thank for your help

Comment: You should try to add some codes and do some tests with the firebase to see if it works or you're **getting the response** or not. Sometimes that `tools -> firebase` might not work properly. Also, please consider accepting my answer if it helped and the errors gone. Firebase issue is not related to this topic. Let me know about the further issues **If** you opened *an another question-thread* by sending the link to me :) Happy coding